# Infinite continuous response variable for logistic distribution? GLMM

Tags: distributions, glmm, logistic-distribution

When I would like to use the generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) for my data analysis, I would have to check the distribution of the response variable so as to decide the link-function.

The result showed that the logistic distribution fit best for my response variable which is a continuous variable from 2 to 20.

When I then try to use the logistic function as the link function for the GLMM, I found that the logistic (logit) function is a finite distribution where the value should lie within 0 to 1.

So my questions are:

1. Can I use use this logit link function when my data violate this assumption?
2. If not, is there any link function I can use which has a similar distribution pattern as the logistic function for infinite continuous data?

[image: Check for potential distribution of the response variable]

[image: Fit for logistic distribution][image: Fit for normal distribution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a response variable that is continuous and takes values between 2 and 20. For this reason alone I do not understand why you want to fit a *generalized* linear mixed model.

I would start with a linear mixed model, and investigate how that fits your data.

You can compare it to the GLMM by comparing predictions.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! 

I thought linear mixed model is just a special case from GLMM, isn't it? 

The reason why I would like to fit a GLMM instead of lmm is because the distribution seems not to be normal which violates the assumptions of a linear mixed model. So I have to use GLMM to handle the non-normal data. 

I am not sure whether my understanding is correct as I just learned all these through books and online source. Any comment is welcomed.

Comment: @JasonYau Yes, LMM is a special case of GLMM using the identity link function. Please also note that there is no requirement for your outcome variable to be normally distributed - the assumption is for the residuals to be normally distributed. If you are concerned about rubustness, the consider using `robustlmm::rlmer()`